# uv4l with multiple usb camera

Tags: raspbian, usb, raspbian-stretch, streaming-video, uv4l

I have 2 usb camera(1,2) and want to stream for each camera. I have used driver = uvc, but when i use default port 8090 for camera1, it works fine. When i explicity stated `--server-option='--port=9000'` for camera2, it doesnt prompt error in terminal but when i access the video from browser, it said connection refused.

The command i used

```
uv4l --driver uvc --device-path 001:005 --config-file=/etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf --auto-video_nr --server-option='--port=9000'
```

Is it related to open port issues on Pi? Or what is the problem?

**Update**

For time being, i duplicated the original uvc.conf as uvc-new.conf and edit the default port, so that for another camera, i specified the config file as uvc-new.conf, and it works out.